# Why does changing the line-height only affect the top of the font?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, typography

I'm working with the dot HTML character to make different color icons. The problem that I'm running into is that the line-height property seems to only affect where the top of the character is placed. I can't get the dot icon to line up with regular text properly, even with a line-height set that matches the standard font-size of the text.

```
HTML
<div>
  <b>Legend:</b>
  <span class="dotib">&#8226;</span>
</div>

CSS
.dotib{font-size: 36pt; line-height: 12pt;}
```

Is there a better way to make this dot behave like I expect it to?

Here's a jsFiddle with this code in it: http://jsfiddle.net/TzFff/

Comment: Where do you expect the bullet (“dot”) to appear? Setting line height is supposed to affect the height of line boxes, and this indirectly affects vertical placement.

Comment: To get a largish bullet-like character, which seems to be the intent, consider using U+25CF BLACK CIRCLE “●” (`&#x25cf;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
.dotib {
    font-size: 36pt; 
    line-height: 12pt;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TzFff/1/